# Xml escape error

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing, escaping

I am new to XML and I need to parse the below XML to JSON using jQuery.

```
<icon IconID="65543" IconType="1" Pane="0" IconTitle="Untitled" ParentType="6"        AWIconColor="#white" AWIconKeywords="" AWIconDesc="" AWCalcIsJavascript="0" AWAntialias="" AWLayer="" AWUpdateVars="0" AWExcludeFromSearch="0" AWPreventErase="0" AWErasePrevious="0" AWDirectToScreen="0" AWIconTransition="[#category:"[internal]", #transition:"None"]" AWDisplayDuration="" AWDisplaySmoothness="" AWAffectedArea="#changingAreaOnly" AWMovable="#never" AWPositioning="#noChange" AWBaseX="" AWBaseY="" AWInitialX="" AWInitialY="" AWEndX="" AWEndY="" AWTimeLimit="">
<subicon type="#image" rect="rect(64, 37, 84, 57)" filename="Untitled.JPG" storage="#internal" attributes="[#drawMode:"opaque", #polyMode:"polyWinding", #constrained:0, #arrow:"arrowNone", #fill:1, #fillForeColor:0, #fillBackColor:16777215, #fillPatMono:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #frame:1, #frameWidth:1, #frameHeight:1, #frameForeColor:0, #frameBackColor:16777215, #framePatMono:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]"/>
```

And i used x2js plugin for this conversion.

but the function always return null.

i guess the problem is with the attributes like
AWIconTransition="[#category:"[internal]", #transition:"None"]"
I dont know how to escape the double quotes inside the square bracket. and I'm badly in need of someones help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not valid, that's what explain the impossible conversion. Replace the quotes in attributes by `&quot;` and add a closing tag to `<icon>` (for instance `<icon><subicon/></icon>`).

Comment: To improve the usefulness of your answer, could you please describe how your proposed changes work and why they solve the original issue? That way, you help future readers to abstract from the original issue and solve similar issues themselves.

Comment: if i am right i used &quot; for " and closed the icon tag. But still i am getting null value

Comment: Did you try to validate your XML snippet ? With xmllint or something else.